# How to access outside function value in state in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to map "socialMediaDetail"   array and get their name . There amny value in this array . Now I am trying to get twitter form this array and then I want to get that value in state . How can I do this please help .

Below is array vakue

```
socialMediaDetails:
socialMediaDetail: Array(5)
0:
link: "HARIRAM@twitter.com"
name: "twitter"
__typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
__proto__: Object
1:
link: "VarnaHERO@facebook.com"
name: "facebook"
__typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
__proto__: Object
2:
link: "linkedIn@linkedin.com"
name: "linkedIn"
__typename: "SocialMediaDetail"
```

Below is code

```
 class UpdateNotificationpreference extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const{navigation}=this.props;
        const{contactDetails,socialMediaDetails}= navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0];
        const{socialMediaDetail}=socialMediaDetails;
        socialMediaDetail.map((data, index) => {
          const twitter= data.name==="twitter";
        });
        this.state = {
          title: 'Update Notification Preference',
          mobile: navigation.state.params.serviceNumber,
          icon: 'sim',
          isChecked: false,
          facebook: navigation.state.params.customerInfo[0].socialMediaDetails.socialMediaDetail[1].name==="facebook"?true : false,
          isTwitter:this.twitter==="twitter"?true:false,

          render(){
          return(
          {this.state.isTwitter === true &&
                        <View style={{marginTop:15}}>
                          <Label img={FAX_MINI} textLabel="FAX"/>
                          <Item style={{borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth:1, marginLeft:0}}>
                            <Input
                              value={this.state.faxNum}
                              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({faxNum:text})}
                            />
                          </Item>
                        </View>}
          )
          }
```

Thanks

Comment: You have made that variable const. Maybe try to change it to let or var?

var something = "hello";

Comment: var is also not working

Comment: Are you saying that you can't get the Twitter value of Const?

Comment: you're doing `socialMediaDetail.map()` but not storing the resulting array anywhere, `.map()` does not mutate the original array , also not returning anything inside the `.map` callback

Comment: are you trying to get twitter link in constructor ?

Comment: yes. I am trying to get const Twitter in state

Comment: const twitter= data.name==="twitter"; this value I want to get here   isTwitter:this.twitter==="twitter"?true:false,

Comment: const twitter= data.name==="twitter" ? "twitter" : ""

Comment: thanks for your time , there are three name in data , twitter , facebook and linkedIn , I have to make 3 variables of this ,get value and access in state , where i'll put condition true or false

Comment: Can you be more specific?

const twitter is only defined in the map function. So an outer method will probably not read it. The other thing is that you haven't added const twitter/socialmediastates to state.